# Array Is Returns a Database Result

Tags: php

The problem is that this way is only returning the last column of the database

```
public function Acentos ( $string ) {

   $Acentos = $this->SelectDados(
       "*",
       "table",
       "",
       array ()
   );

   foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

       $table = array (

          $List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome'] )

        );

    }

    return strtr ( $string, $table );
}
```

I tried to do like this

```
$Dados = array ();

foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

    $table = array (

       $Dados[] = $List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $Dados[] = $List['nome'] )

    );

 }
```

With array_push gives the following error

```
public function Acentos ( $string ) {

   $Table = array();
   $Acentos = $this->SelectDados(
      "*",
      "table",
      "",
      array ()
    );

    foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

        array_push ( $Table,

         $List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome'] )

     );

  }

  return strtr ( $string, $Table );
 }
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

As I understand it array_push does not accept special characters `=>` how to fix this?

Comment: Use `$table[] = …` to add a new element to that array.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'`

Comment: _“As I understand it array_push does not accept special characters `=>`”_ - this has nothing to do with array_push in particular, but with you not being aware of context. This syntax is for use _inside_ of an array context - so either `array( … )` or `[ … ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

means that PHP expected something different than `=>`.

**Cause**:

You're creating an array without the `array` keyword:

```
foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

        array_push ( $Table,

         $List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome'] ) // << here

     );

  }
```

You must define the new array passed to array_push as this:

```
foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

        array_push ( $Table,

         array($List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome']) )

     );

  }
```

Complete code:

```
public function Acentos ( $string ) {

   $Table = array();
   $Acentos = $this->SelectDados(
      "*",
      "table",
      "",
      array ()
    );

    foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

        array_push ( $Table,

         array($List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome']) )

     );

  }

  return strtr ( $string, $Table );
 }
```

Comment: Very good, it worked perfect, but I didn't get the expected result

Comment: You're welcome :) What's precisely your expected result?

Comment: Replace `my-slug` for `My Slug`